# Is it a good practice to mock the other public method in same class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

For example:

```
public class NumberService {

public boolean isNaturalNumber(int num) {
    return num > 0;
}

public String getClassificationInfo(int num) {
    return isNaturalNumber(num) ? num + "is a natural number" : num + "is not a natural number";
}
}
```

Here are two public method, and the method `getClassificationInfo` called the method `isNaturalNumber`.

Is it a good practice to mock `isNaturalNumber` when testing `getClassificationInfo`?

Like this:

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class NumberServiceTest {

@Spy
private NumberService numberService;

@Test
public void test_getClassificationInfo_when_is_natural_number() {
    int num = generateInt();

    doReturn(true).when(numberService).isNaturalNumber(num);

    String classificationInfo = numberService.getClassificationInfo(num);

    assertThat(classificationInfo).isEqualTo(num + "is a natural number");
}

@Test
public void test_getClassificationInfo_when_is_not_natural_number() {
    int num = generateInt();

    doReturn(false).when(numberService).isNaturalNumber(num);

    String classificationInfo = numberService.getClassificationInfo(num);

    assertThat(classificationInfo).isEqualTo(num + "is not a natural number");
}

// the other test for isNaturalNumber

private int generateInt() {
    return new Random().nextInt();
}
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use a spy. If you are testing `NumberService`, then it should be the real class. In your example, the implementation of `getClassificationInfo()` depends on the implementation of `isNaturalNumber()`. If you get the mocking of that wrong, your test may pass, but in reality the implementation could still be wrong.

Comment: you shouldn't mock the class itself rather create the object of that class and test the result... mocking comes into picture only if you have dependencies into your class .. for example, if you had other services on `NumberService`, then you would have mocked that service and stub those mocks

Comment: Mock nothing, unless your tests become slow - then mock dependencies which makes tests slow(accessing external resources such database, webservice, filesystem etc.), unless preparing for test become very very very complex - then you mock dependencies with complex configuration.

Comment: My questions: is `isNaturalNumber()` used by any other Code? Does it really need to be *public*? If not then it is just an *implementation detail* that should bot be tested explicitly.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle yes, isNaturalNumber is used by other class

Comment: Then next question arises: does this other behavior using `isNaturalNumber()` really belong to this other classes or is that other behavior so closely related to `getClassificationInfo()` that it "fells good" to have it in this class? *(Don't get me wrong: You don't need to justify your design to me, just answer this to yourself...)*

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case it does not make sense to mock the method called.  It is, however, not just because of the fact that it is a method of the same class.  In fact, sometimes methods of the same class are introduced specifically to allow them to be mocked.  For example, if within your class you process some data you obtain via file I/O, you could isolate the file I/O into a method of its own.  Then, you could test the data processing with a mocked version of your file I/O method.

However, in this case there is no good reason to mock `isNaturalNumber` in the tests for `getClassificationInfo`: The method `isNaturalNumber` has deterministic behaviour and does not lead to unacceptably long execution time.  It also seems unlikely that you gain much by simulating the case that `isNaturalNumber` intentionally behaves wrongly in one of the tests of `getClassificationInfo`.

You don't have to mock everything dogmatically. For example, you also don't mock standard library math functions like `sin` or `cos`, because they also don't cause problems in most cases.  Mocking should be done for a reason.  Therefore, if you consider mocking a function or method, you should know which problem you are about to solve.  If there is no problem to solve, don't mock.

Comment: +1 In my decades long experience with mocking libraries, I've seen people using them as a crutch much more often than not. Overuse of mocking leads to poor tests of little or no value, as this question shows, since `NumberService` can easily be tested with no mocking at all.

Answer (score 0):

No Its not good practice because we should mock stubs where other module/class object is involve.

eg:

```
public class A{
   private B aObj;

   public void aDoingSomeBWork(){
      aObj.someMethod();
      someLogic();
  }
   private/public/any modifier void someLogic(){
     //some logic
   }
}

public class B{
   public void someMethod(){}
}
```

then in that you should mock B's someMethod() but should not A's someLogic() beacuse you are unit testing A's aDoingSomeBWork() method. if you mock someLogic(); in unit testing then there might be a case your code break.